# Doctrine 2 entity with join column inserting null values

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

It's most likely I've done something wrong, but I have an entity like so, that when inserted, inserts NULL for its user_id column (despite my setting it).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sales_contacts_tags")
 */
class SalesContactTag
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     */
    protected $sales_contact_id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime");
     */
    protected $time_recorded;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string");
     */
    protected $type;


    /**
     * @var \Foo\Entity\User $user
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Foo\Entity\User", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $sales_contact_id
     */
    public function setSalesContactId($sales_contact_id)
    {
        $this->sales_contact_id = $sales_contact_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSalesContactId()
    {
        return $this->sales_contact_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $time_recorded
     */
    public function setTimeRecorded($time_recorded)
    {
        $this->time_recorded = $time_recorded;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTimeRecorded()
    {
        return $this->time_recorded;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $type
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $user_id
     */
    public function setUserId($user_id)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param \LaunchfireUser\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return \LaunchfireUser\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

When I fetch one of these entities, everything is fine.  The multiple relationship entities are listed as expected.  When I insert, however, the user_id column is null.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help as always.

Answer (score 5):

Your `user_id` and `user` fields are conflicting with each other since they are both keyed to the "user_id" database field.  Your best bet is to remove the `user_id` field and call `setUser()` before persisting.

Comment: This worked for me. I had almost exactly the same scenario with different classes. When I removed the foreign_object_id in favor of foreign_object, I had to look very closely at the relationships I built on both sides of the relationships. Once those were clean it worked perfectly. Hope this helps others with the same problem! TYVM!

Comment: @Kevin Sharp After removing the user_id field, where to store the user's id reference?
Then user_id column would be filled with null values.

Comment: @jfgrissom when you remove the foreign object Id. Where should the user_id to be saved? Calling the SetUser() wouldn't save the user_id